# Is there a way to feed a cached response to Retrofit?

Tags: android, sqlite, retrofit, okhttp

For various reasons (one of which being that I have no control on the REST server) I cannot use the standard HTTP cache with OkHTTP.

The idea would be to use Retrofit to work with the services and store the responses in a local cache (SQLite). 
The problem then is how to feed a cached response to Retrofit. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just curious: why won't the standard cache work?

Comment: @JesseWilson for two reasons: the server always returns no-cache and I need this mechanism to work when offline as well (maybe I can work around this with max-stale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OkHttp [interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors). You'll need Retrofit ≥ 1.9 and OkHttp ≥ 2.2.

Comment: It looks like network interceptors still need the request to go through the network before I can manipulate the response so that's not good for my use case. And the application interceptor would not run if there's no network connection if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Application interceptor runs even if the network fails.

Comment: Hi, I am very interested in this way of solving caching via Retrofit and Interceptors, do you have some code/example to share? I would be happy to get how it really works

Comment: I should probably describe my issue:
- backend logics is based on `Last-Modified` flag, which I am intercepting to my requests as `If-Modified-Since`. But I never get cached responses, only `304` code from server. Adding Response interceptor does not help, as due to some reason `cacheResponse` is `null`, as well as `cacheControl` even if I force adding `Cache-Control: public, max-age=9600` to all my requests.

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli  if you found any work around with interceptor. please have a look at this question and shed some light on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525511/okhttp-interceptors-to-intercept-when-internet-is-disabled